# python nested if statement with user input does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I dont know why, but when I start to test this, no matter which letter i enter, it drops out print("THIS FILE IS DELETED") and no other options. Something must be wrong with nesting if statement.

```
import os, shutil, send2trash

def delete_files(folder):
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            full_file_name = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
            size = os.path.getsize(full_file_name)
            if size > 100000000:
                print(filename, size)
                print("Do you want to delete this file?")
                confirm = input("Y or N? ")
                if confirm == "Y" or "y":
                    print("THIS FILE IS DELETED")
                    #send2trash.send2trash(filename)
                elif confirm == "N" or "n":
                    print("Let`s keep this file!")
delete_files(r"M:\Tables_Field\Processing\!-=ieksejie dokumenti=-\!Emīls")
```

Comment: because `if confirm == "Y" or "y":` is *wrong*. It should be `if confirm == "Y" or confirm == "y":`

Comment: or `if confirm in ('Y', 'y')` or `if confirm.lower() == 'y'`

Comment: Actually, `if confirm == 'Y' or 'y'` is _not_ wrong. It just doesn't do what you _expect_ it to do. `'Y' or 'y'` returns `'Y'` (the first true-ish value), so if you enter a `'Y'`, it will work fine.

Comment: @ForceBru the important part is that it parses as `if (confirm=="Y") or ("y")`, and one of those things is always truthy, so it breaks down to an `if True` statement.

Comment: OMG! How I didnt saw that!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys :)